# Adding a language code in my URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have been advised to add a language code to my url - therefore i want my homepage to read http://www.freebetoffersonline.com/en/index.php instead of http://www.freebetoffersonline.com/index.php therefore can somebody please assist me??

do i have to change the html in order to add this

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you'd you want to do this exactly but using .htaccess you could write something to ignore that first entry and load everything after that like it was the root of the website. Keep in mind this would only make sense if you actually had different languages and used this in your code.

Comment: woorank has flagged it up as something i need to change to improve my websites rating

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion is to use an get object lang=en/other language code like  http://www.freebetoffersonline.com/index.php?lang=en this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest same as '.Madan Ram' http://www.freebetoffersonline.com/index.php?lang=en.

Or you can make a folder named 'en' and put your whole web site in that folder. This will help you to create different folders for different languages. But you have to make a copy of whole web page again and again regarding the language in every folder. And this is bulky.